# I need to add together multiple inputs, which are read only totals of 2 other inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, addition

I am needing help in basically adding together the sum total inputs, to make them add together to create a final amount.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, there can be multiple inputs, and the person can add more with the click of the button, the code works so the quantity and the unit price add together, however I am after the subtotals adding together automatically to keep updating the gbp total.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" oninput="calculate(this)" id="qid1" data-quantity name="qamount" min="0" data-validation="number" class="qinput txt" value="{{Quantity}}" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="max100" class="dinput" value="{{Details}}" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" oninput="calculate(this)" id="uid1" data-unitprice name="uamount" min="0" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float" class="uinput txt" value="{{UnitPrice}}" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input readonly id="subsubtotal" name="totalamount" class="sinput txt" value="{{Subtotal}}" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="additembtton">
  <button id="bttonitem">Add Invoice Item</button>
  <input id="bttonitem1" type="submit" value="Save" />
  <span class="gbptotal">GBP Total</span>
  <span id="totalplus" class="totalsub">£0.00</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
//code that multiplies the quantity and unit price input boxes
function calculate(obj) {
    var tr = obj.parentNode.parentNode;
    var myBox1 = tr.cells[0].children[0].value;
    var myBox2 = tr.cells[2].children[0].value;
    var result = tr.cells[3].children[0];
    var myResult = parseFloat(myBox1) * parseFloat(myBox2);
    result.value = myResult.toFixed(2);
}
```

The javascript above is what works already, this multiplies both the quantity and unit price together, I am struggling with how I would do the same with the sub total, to add all the sub totals together (however many there may be), and display the final total in where the £0.00 is.

Comment: Can your users order fractional parts of an item? This is entirely irrelevant to your question, but from a UI perspective the decimals seem an unlikely requirement. :) Oh, and are you really using jQuery? It's in no way required for this, and seems redundant to include if it's not being used elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, and yes:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="bttonitem1" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="gbpTotal()">

function gbpTotal(){

    var total = 0;

    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.sinput');

    inputs.forEach(function(e){

        total += parseFloat(e.value);

    });

    document.querySelector('#totalplus').textContent = total;

};
```

You might want to trigger the function anytime they click out of an input instead of on the save

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, this effected it slightly however it only changed the £0.00 to NaN and then it did not do anything afterwards, will have a play around and see whats what

Comment: My solution doesn't take into consideration when someone calculates the same line more than once, which would result in a double dip of that subtotal, but I'll revise my answer to accommodate that, one moment.

Comment: @JacobHarrison See the edit in my answer, that should work.

Comment: That does again effect the total, however instead of adding the subtotals together, it just shows the totals for each input individually next to each other. As in it looked like this (when the total was 144 in each subtotal box) 144.00144.00, instead of it adding them together, thank you for the help, will have a little play around also and see if I can sort it

Comment: @JacobHarrison Look at my answer, I've added a `parseFloat()` to force a number because what was happening was the value was coming through as a string and they were concatenating like you were seeing, but now it should be a number which will do the addition.

Comment: Oh yeah, my mistake. Thank you for your help, credit to you, it is sorted now

Comment: @JacobHarrison If truly solved, mark this as an answer so people don't keep looking into this question thinking it's not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to query for all the inputs that are from the same column when it's time to total them up. This is best achieved by ensuring that the inputs in each column belong to the same CSS class. This way, it doesn't matter how many rows you wind up with and you won't have to worry about rows or cells, just inputs that belong to the same class.

So, here's an example that shows how to get the total of the total column, but the same approach would be used for any other columns.

```js
var totals = document.querySelectorAll(".total");
var output = document.getElementById("total");
var btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
  var tot = null;
  // Convert the node list of inputs that hold totals into an array and loop through that array
  Array.prototype.slice.call(totals).forEach(function(element){
    // Get the sum of the values
    tot += parseFloat(element.value);
  });
  
  // Display the output
  output.textContent = tot;

});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>  
      <th>Total</th>    
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>  
      <td><input type="text" class="total"></td>    
    </tr>  
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>  
      <td><input type="text" class="total"></td>    
    </tr>  
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="price"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="qty"></td>  
      <td><input type="text" class="total"></td>    
    </tr>      
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="total"></div>
<button>Get Totals</button>
```

Comment: use reduce instead of forEach maybe?

Comment: @FrankCamara Sure. But, that part is not really the issue.

Comment: Thank you also, will give this a shot, appreciate the reply